# Where is pg_shadow table located?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello I am checking `pg_catalog` database and I cannot see `pg_shadow` table is it normal? Basically I want to retrieve users and passwords pg_user is showing ****** always also it doesn't show pg_user here but when I run `select * from pg_user` it's working is it normal?

I see only these tables below at `pg_catalog`. How can I get stored hashes except that table?

```
pg_aggregate
pg_am
pg_amop
pg_amproc
pg_attrdef
pg_attribute
pg_auth_members
pg_cast
pg_class
pg_constraint
pg_conversion
pg_database
pg_depend
pg_description
pg_enum
pg_foreign_data_wrapper
pg_foreign_server
pg_index
pg_inherits
pg_language
pg_largeobject
pg_listener
pg_namespace
pg_opclass
pg_operator
pg_opfamily
pg_pltemplate
pg_proc
pg_rewrite
pg_shdepend
pg_shdescription
pg_statistic
pg_suthid
pg_tablespace
pg_trigger
pg_ts_config
pg_ts_config_map
pg_ts_dict
pg_ts_parser
pg_ts_template
pg_type
pg_user_mapping
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a view, not a table.  It's in `pg_catalog`.

The base table is `pg_authid`.

All tables with passwords in them are superuser only.

Comment: select * from pg_catalog.pg_shadow right command to retrieve that ? or is there any other way to get stored hash ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that should work.  The view selects from pg_catalog.pg_authid, so you could also select from there, but pg_shadow just selects roles that can actually log in, which is probably more helpful.

Comment: 'PostgreSQL 8.4.20 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18), 64-bit' version that i try ... i see columns there but they don't any value i mean empty i guess is there any other way to see hashes ?

Comment: There is an other database name information_schema and tables below is it usefull to retrieve hashes ?
Database: information_schema
[7 tables]
sql_features
sql_ianguages
sql_implementation_info
sql_packages
sql_parts
sql_sizing
sql_sizing_profiles